# php how to replace img style in all images in output

Tags: php

i need to replace in all images in output their style parameters 
for example

```
$output = '<p><img src="" style="float: left; width: 600px; height: 400px">
              some text <img src="" style="float: right; width: 600px; height: 300px">';
```

i need

```
$output = '<p><img src="" class="alignleft" width="600" height="400"> some text <img src="" class="alignright" width="600" height="300">';
```

please help

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself i.e some code to get help form SO member?

Comment: Did you try preg_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: i am new in php so asking here

Comment: Whats you problem? Do you want to replace within the $output variable or replace this in all your code files?

Comment: in $output, its grab html from form powered by ckeditor, that editor embeds style="" in img tag. but i need read that style and use their values in width="xxxpx" height="xxxpx". ps: sorry about my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved

```
            $output = preg_replace_callback('#<img (.+) style="(.+)" />#isU', 
        function($matches) {
            $styles = explode('; ', $matches[2]);
            foreach ($styles as $i) {
                if (strstr($i, 'width')) $styles['w'] = $i;
                if (strstr($i, 'height')) $styles['h'] = $i;
            }
            $width = $styles['w'];
            $width = str_replace('width:', '', $width);
            $width = str_replace('px', '', $width);
            $height = $styles['h'];
            $height = str_replace('height:', '', $height);
            $height = str_replace('px', '', $height);
            return '<img ' . $matches[1] . ' width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '">';
        }
        , $output);
```

Comment: ill give u a thumbs up for answering your own question